# How to make scatter graph axis start at a particular value in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a scatter graph, with values on the x-axis going from 0.8 to 1.1 . However, the scatter graph that I've made displays the x-axis going all the way from 0 to 1.1, and as a result a large part of the graph is empty (from 0 to 0.8). I want to get rid of this and have the axis start only at 0.8 - How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 2):

I would make a sample on Excel for Microsoft 365.

Just right click the X-Axis > format Axis, then you may set the minimum value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Very simple and general answer:

Right click the graphic portion of the axis you wish to change; a menu will appear, select "Edit axis", "Properties" or similar (actual choice depends on Excel version, or if using e.g. LibreOffice).

A dialog, panel or similar will open; again depending on the actual software and version.